# Adding a row to a FITS table with astropy

Tags: astropy, fits

I have a problem which ought to be trivial but seems to have been massively over-complicated by the column-based nature of FITS BinTableHDU.

The script I'm writing should be trivial: iterate through a FITS file and write a subset of rows to an identically formatted FITS file, reducing the row count from c700k/3.6GB to  about 350 rows. I have processed the input file and have each row that I want to save in a python array of FITS records:

```
    outarray = []

    self.indata=Table.read(self.infile, hdu=1)
    
    for r in self._indata:

        RecPassesFilter = FilterProc(r, self)

        #
        # Add to output array only if passes all filters...  
        #   
        if RecPassesFilter:
            outarray.append(r)
```

Now, I've created an empty BintableHDU with exactly the same columns and formats and I want to add the filtered data:

[...much omitted code later...}

```
            mycols =  []
            for inputcol in self._coldefs:
                mycols.append(fits.Column(name=inputcol.name, format=inputcol.format))

           # Next line should produce an empty BinTableHDU in the identical format to the output data

            SaveData = fits.BinTableHDU.from_columns(mycols)

            for s in self._outdata:
                SaveData.data.append(s)
```

Now that last line not only fails, but every variant of it (SaveData.append() or .add_row() or whatever) also fails with a "no such method" error. There seems to be a singular lack of documentation on how to do the trivial task of adding a record. Clearly I am missing something, but two days later I'm still drawing a blank.

Can anyone point me in the right direction here?

Comment: The lower-level `astropy.io.fits` module is not really designed for general table manipulation.  Since you're already using `Table` to read the file, you can also create an empty `Table` with the same columns to output to using `Table.add_row` as explained in these documents: https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/table/modify_table.html#quick-overview

Comment: Thanks for the response. I need to make sure that the new FITS file I create has identical format to the original. I could not see how you can do this using just astropy.Table as there seems no mechanism to specify the [FITS] column format. Is there a way to do so?

Comment: One way, though I don't know if it's the very best, is you can read a table from a FITS file like: `t1 = Table.read('path/to/table.fits')` then create a new empty table with the dtype from the first one: `t2 = Table(dtype=t1.dtype)`.  Then start using `t2.add_row`.  It's true this gives less obvious control of some of the lower-level FITS details like the other `T<AAAA>` header keywords, but I think there are ways to add those too.

Comment: You can also use a combination of `Table` and the lower-level FITS code.  If you can provide more details on exactly what the output should be I might be able to conjure something up

Answer (score 0):

OK, I managed to resolve this with some brute force and nested iterations essentially to create column data arrays on the fly. It's not much in terms of code and I don't care that it's inefficient as I won't need to run it too often. Example code here:

```
            with fits.open(self._infile) as HDUSet:
                tableHDU=HDUSet[1]
                self._coldefs = tableHDU.columns

            
            FITScols =  []
            for inputcol in self._coldefs:
                NewColData = []
                for r in self._outdata:
                    NewColData.append(r[inputcol.name])
                FITScols.append(fits.Column(name=inputcol.name, format=inputcol.format, array=NewColData))

            SaveData = fits.BinTableHDU.from_columns(FITScols)

            SaveData.writeto(fname)
```

This solves my problem for a 350 row subset. I haven't yet dared try it for the 250K row subset that I need for the next part of my project!

Comment: I'm still not sure how this is related to the original question you asked which was about appending data row-wise to a table.  As far as I can tell this is copying the column data from one table to another, but in a way that seems more involved than I think is necessary.

Comment: It's because adding data row-wise to a table format that is column-oriented is a painful task. Rather than store a row-by-row, you have to store column-by-column. It's equivalent to adding a column to a table in a SQL database when every row has a different value for that column, and you can't change the definition of the original table to boot!

Comment: I agree, I just thought that was your original goal.

Answer (score 0):

I just recalled that [`BinTableHDU.from_columns`](https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/io/fits/api/tables.html#astropy.io.fits.BinTableHDU.from_columns) takes an `nrows` argument.  If you pass that along with the columns of an existing table HDU, it will copy the column structure but initialize subsequent rows with empty data:

```py
>>> hdul = fits.open('astropy/io/fits/tests/data/table.fits')
>>> table = hdul[1]
>>> table.columns
ColDefs(
    name = 'target'; format = '20A'
    name = 'V_mag'; format = 'E'
)
>>> table.data
FITS_rec([('NGC1001', 11.1), ('NGC1002', 12.3), ('NGC1003', 15.2)],
         dtype=(numpy.record, [('target', 'S20'), ('V_mag', '>f4')]))
>>> new_table = fits.BinTableHDU.from_columns(table.columns, nrows=5)
>>> new_table.columns
ColDefs(
    name = 'target'; format = '20A'
    name = 'V_mag'; format = 'E'
)
>>> new_table.data
FITS_rec([('NGC1001', 11.1), ('NGC1002', 12.3), ('NGC1003', 15.2),
          ('',  0. ), ('',  0. )],
         dtype=(numpy.record, [('target', 'S20'), ('V_mag', '<f4')]))
```

As you can see, this still copies the data from the original columns.  I think the idea behind this originally was for adding new rows to an existing table.  However, you can also initialize a completely empty new table by passing `fill=True`:

```py
>>> new_table_zeroed = fits.BinTableHDU.from_columns(table.columns, nrows=5, fill=True)
>>> new_table_zeroed.data
FITS_rec([('', 0.), ('', 0.), ('', 0.), ('', 0.), ('', 0.)],
         dtype=(numpy.record, [('target', 'S20'), ('V_mag', '<f4')]))
```